# Spring Not a Managed Type class

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

Note: I`m not using spring boot

All the errors in here

> Error creating bean with name 'writeData': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in
> com.aykut.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories
> declared on SpringConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type:
> class com.aykut.modal.User
>
> Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.aykut.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories
> declared on SpringConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type:
> class com.aykut.modal.User
>
> Not a managed type: class com.aykut.modal.User

[image: Project tree]

User class

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String surname;

    public User(Integer id, String name, String surname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

Spring config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "com.aykut.repository"
})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.aykut"})
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

User Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

I am just trying to write data to my Postgres database using the spring batch.

Comment: Which indicates that your entitymanager setup is wrong. Also please remove `@Repository` from `UserRepository` it is useless as Spring Data uses other means to detect repositories.

Comment: Actually this was very helpful i looked my JpaConfig file and edited setPackagesToScan method to this
`factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.aykut.modal"});` 
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe when you using Persistence tool of Inteliji for generate entity, but also checked to 'generate persistence.xml file' => this file will make your project error, please checking and delete this file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error happen repeatedly until I found that I had imported `jakarta.persistence.Entity` instead of `javax.persistence.Entity`.  Once I changed it to javax everything worked.